# Limit for Matrix expression

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions

Let's assume that $Q_0$ is $3\times 3$ matrix with $\det Q_0\neq0 $ and

$$
Q_{i+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left[ Q_i+(Q_i^{-1})^T \right]
$$

I need to find next limit: $\lim _{i \to +\infty}$$Q_i$. In other words I need to find such $Q_i$ that $\left|Q_{i+1} - Q_i\right| < \epsilon$. Does anybody know, is it possible to find such kind of limits with *Mathematica*?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but do you need more assumptions on the determinant at each iteration ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks that just says that $Q_0$ is invertible. The trick is then showing that $\det (Q_1 + (Q^{-1}_1)^T) \neq 0$.

Comment: To see the limit appearing for random matrices one can try `n = 3;
Q0= RandomReal[{-100, 100}, {n, n}];
res = NestWhileList[(# + Transpose@Inverse@#)/2 &, Q0, 
   Norm[#1 - #2] > 10^-8 &, 5, 10^4];
limit = Last@res
ListAnimate[MatrixPlot[#] & /@ res]`

Comment: `q0={{-1, -1, 1/5 (-2 - 4 I Sqrt[6])}, {1, -1, -1}, {0, 1, 1}}` is invertible but `q1 = 1/2 (q0 + Transpose[Inverse[q0]])` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to prove that starting from an invertible matrix each iteration will give an invertible matrix. Also, I'm going to consider real matrices only (because of what I have in the comments).

We can start by the singular value decompostion of `q0 = Dot[u, w0, Transpose[v]]` where `w` is diagonal. Then you can easily convince yourself that the same decomposition holds at each iteration, i.e. `q1 = Dot[u, w1, Transpose[v]]` where `w1 = 1/2 (w0 + Transpose[Inverse[w0]])` and so on. All matrices in the last equation are diagonal, so the equality holds equivalently for each diagonal element.

The solution to  that equation is given by :

```
RSolve[{a[i + 1] == 1/2 (a[i] + 1/a[i]), a[0] == a0}, a[i], i]
(* {{a[i] -> Coth[2^i ArcCoth[a0]]}} *)
```

and you can then take the limit from here.

Check :

```
SeedRandom[3];
q0 = RandomReal[UniformDistribution[], {3, 3}];
svd = SingularValueDecomposition[q0];

Nest[1/2 (# + Transpose[Inverse[#]]) &, q0, 10] == 
 (Dot[svd[[1]], 
      DiagonalMatrix[Coth[2^(10) ArcCoth[#]] & /@ Diagonal[svd[[2]]]],            
      Transpose[svd[[3]]]
  ] // Chop)
(* True *)
```

Comment: In general starting from an invertible need not always provide another. Take `{{0,1},{-1,0}}` for example, as its inverse is also its negation. In general I believe that when the sequence stays in the invertible family, the convergence is to a diagonal matrix with +-1 in each position on the main diagonal.

Comment: Thanks, this code seems to work well, however as I understand in order to obtain $Q$ matrix I always need to perform SVD. SVD works more slowly than this iteration formula 
which actually perform Polar Decomposition.

Comment: You need to do it only once for each matrix `Q0` you need to consider.